# Open Firewall to a dynamic public IP address but not via IP

Tags: firewall, external-connection

I have a server firewall set to allow incoming traffic only from specifics IP for security reasons.

I sometimes have to connect to it from outside office and I don't have a static public IP there, but a dynamic one. So writing an email and get it change every time is not an option.

I was thinking if there may be some other "static" infos other than the IP that recognize my device and I can ask to open the firewall on that?

I know I could use DNS, but unfortunately the DNS I have is very used in Italy because it belongs to the Vodafone company and that would open the firewall to too many devices.

Perhaps my Mac Hardware UUID? (F944F643-9611-5A84-9B2B-**********) or any other "fixed" properties?

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways to achieve what you want (from least to more safe):

1. Just use non-standard port number.
2. Port knocking method - you send sequence of packets with known properties to open the port for your current ip. If you use the linux on your firewall, you can read [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-port-knocking-using-only-iptables-on-an-ubuntu-vps).
3. Use VPN.

Choice depends on firewall software features and your skills.

Comment: Wow, great, can you refer me to something about port-knocking?

Comment: I've added link to the good tutorial for iptables port-knocking into the answer.